# Cannot access haproxy stats socket with systemd

Tags: systemd, socat, haproxy

I am trying to disable a haproxy frontend from a systemd service in Debian 9 (haproxy 1.7.5-2).  The default config sets up admin access via a unix socket at /run/haproxy/admin.sock so I use socat (1.7.3.1):

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo disable frontend http | /usr/bin/socat stdio unix-connect:/run/haproxy/admin.sock'
```

This works perfectly when I run it manually as root.  It also works if I omit spawning a new sh instance too:

```
echo disable frontend http | /usr/bin/socat stdio unix-connect:/run/haproxy/admin.sock
```

When I attempt to run the same command as a systemd service, I consistently get a *Connection refused* error and I can't figure out why.  Here is a simplified service file that reproduces the error:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test unit
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=false
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/test -x /usr/bin/socat
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo disable frontend http | /usr/bin/socat stdio unix-connect:/run/haproxy/admin.sock'
```

The relevant error from `systemctl status test.service`:

`sh[1305]: 2020/05/09 12:26:23 socat[1308] E connect(5, AF=1 "/run/haproxy/admin.sock", 25): Connection refused`

I verified the path exists and I can run the command exactly as written in the *ExecStart* stanza manually as root immediately following the systemd failure. I thought I messed up the syntax for systemd, but that doesn't appear to be the problem.  The same error occurs if I use bash or zsh instead of /bin/sh too.  This has been driving me crazy for a couple of days.  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps the unit is starting just too soon after the network is online so the socket exists but no one is listening? Try adding an `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 10` just to see.

Comment: @meuh the sleep addition did eliminate the problem so thank you.  The unit is run on a timer despite my reference to `network-online.target`.  I can run `systemctl start test.service` as many times as I desire guaranteeing a failure each time.  It still isn't clear to me how systemd's interaction affects the timing here although it is clearly a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [meuh's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585616/cannot-access-haproxy-stats-socket-with-systemd#comment1091262_585616), I added a retry option to socat:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo disable frontend http | /usr/bin/socat stdio unix-connect:/run/haproxy/admin.sock,retry=2'
```

Still not what's different about launching through systemd, but it's working for now.